# aMember paypal ipn does not create automatic first payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, recurring-billing, amember

I'm using aMember for user registrations and payments.
Everything works fine even the paypal payment etc.

The product i'm testing with has a fee of $0 for the first month then $100 recurring every month.

Now, the ipn gets back, and i receive an invoice nr, but my amember does not create the first product for the user to access, i have to create it manually?

I checked the logs and it is clean.

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

So you are not seeing the first payment?  If you are using subscription buttons, and are using IPN to set this this up within your system, you should see an ipn for the profile created.  You will not see an IPN for the first payment until the month has passed. You would want the script to create this on the profile created IPN POST.

Comment: Hi, I'm not using subscription buttons, i use aMember's default paypal integration. After the user registration, the user is redirected to Paypal to make the payment for the subscription they selected. After the payment was successful they return, and i can see via the admin, that the ipn returned the invoice number. But it does not create the first payment in aMember, so the user still cannot use the app that he/she payed for.